# Кавычки в повествовании от первого лица

Tags: кавычки

Есть текст, полностью написанный от первого лица.
И внутри абзаца, где описаны мысли героини, есть такое предложение:

Нет, в браке тоже не всегда так, уговаривала себя я.

Затем дальше идут размышления также от первого лица.
Нужно ли заключать в этом случае речь в кавычки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Корректно: "Нет, в браке тоже не всегда так," — уговаривала я себя.

Правило: 
Независимо от места, занимаемого по отношению к словам автора, кавычками выделяется внутренняя речь — невысказанные мысли:

Смотрю вслед ему и думаю: «Зачем живут такие люди?» (М. Г.); «Что-то в ней есть жалкое всё-таки», — подумал я (Ч.).

> См.: Розенталь. Д.Э. Справочник по русскому языку: Орфография и пунктуация.